# Issue with my clearInterval function

Tags: javascript, html, web, clock, clearinterval

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function init()
{
  timeDisplay = document.createTextNode ( "" );
  document.getElementById("clock").appendChild ( timeDisplay );
}

function updateClock()
{
  var currentTime = new Date ();

  var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
  var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
  var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

  // Adds zeros if required
  currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;
  currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;

  // Decides whether AM or PM
  var timeOfDay = ( currentHours < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";

  // Convert the hours component to 12-hour format if needed
  currentHours = ( currentHours > 12 ) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;

  // Convert an hours component of "0" to "12"
  currentHours = ( currentHours == 0 ) ? 12 : currentHours;

  // Creates the display string
  var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + timeOfDay;

  // Updates the time display
  document.getElementById("clock").firstChild.nodeValue = currentTimeString;
}

// -->
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="week9live.css" />
</head>

<body onload="updateClock(); setInterval('updateClock()', 1000 )">
<h1>A live clock in Javascript</h1>
<div>
  <p>The time according to your pc is </p> <span id="clock">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
</br>
<button type ="button" onclick = "clearInterval('updateClock()')">Stop Clock</button>
<button type="button" onclick="setInterval('updateClock()', 1000)">Start Clock</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I have this lot of HTML which I've used to generate a live clock. I've then been tasked to create two buttons, one which stops the clock, and then a second that restarts it. My setInterval function works fine, but I cannot for the life of me work out why the clearInterval function isn't working. Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: `clearInterval` expects an ID returned by `setInterval`. It's always worth reading some documentation instead of assuming how things work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval

Answer (score 3):

You need to save the value that's **returned** from `setInterval`, and pass *that* into your call to `clearInterval`.

```
var idForClear = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
```

and then

```
clearInterval(idForClear);
```

This will be a lot easier if you ditch the inline dom level 0 handlers and do something like this

```
<button id="stopBtn" type ="button">Stop Clock</button>
<button id="startBtn" type="button">Start Clock</button>

var idForClear;
document.getElementById("startBtn").onclick = function() {
    idForClear = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
};
document.getElementById("stopBtn").onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(idForClear);
};
```

Just make sure you place this script at the **bottom** of your page's body, to make sure `document.getElementById` doesn't get called before you dom is ready.

---

Also, it's usually considered evil to call `setTimeout` or `setInterval` with a string.  When you're not in an inline handler, instead of this

```
setInterval('updateClock()', 1000);
```

You'd want to pass in a **function**

```
setInterval(function() { updateClock(); }, 1000);
```

But of course updateClock is a function, too, so the above is a more noisy equivalent to

```
setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. I've added the code you provided to the bottom of the page's body, but the button still doesn't seem to work. What code from my page needs deleting, or changing? Not the hottest when it comes to Javascript :P

Comment: @user1121477 - I'd start debugging by having the start and stop buttons do a setInterval that just does a console.log - then check the chrome console that it's working.  Then slowly add in all of your clock stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The `clearInterval` function should receive an id that is generated by `setInterval`. Something like:

```
var theid = setInterval('updateClock()', 1000);
clearInterval(theid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass id of setInterval in clearInterval
See: [ClearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)